# For this bijection, how would one find an inverse, domain and range?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, discrete-mathematics

Take the following bijection

$g(x) =\left\{ \begin{matrix}
2|x|-1 ~~~~~ x<0\\
2x ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~x\geq 0 
\end{matrix} \right.$

Where $g: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$.

How would you find the inverse of the function (and it's domain and range)? I ended up with

$g^{-1}(x) =\left\{ \begin{matrix}
\frac{1-x}{2}~~~~~~~~~~~ x<0\\
\frac{x}{2} ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~x\geq 0 
\end{matrix} \right.$

Which I do not think is correct. Also, how does the fact that $g: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ affect the results?

Comment: the inverse is only defined for positive $x$, hence it is not correct

Comment: to define the inverse split the function into 2 cases: $x$ odd and $x$ even

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at a table of values. -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3 are mapped onto 5, 3, 1, 0, 2, 4, 6. For the inverse mapping even and odd numbers will be treated differently. If you put $y=g(x)$ calculating the inverse functions gives

$x=g^{-1}(y) =\left\{ \begin{matrix}
\frac{1-y}{2}~~~~~~~~~~~ x<0\\
\frac{y}{2} ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~x\geq 0 
\end{matrix} \right.$

but you need to specify conditions on $y$ instead of conditions on $x$.